# SceneKit scene being letter boxed on larger screens

Tags: ios, scenekit

After upgrading my test devices to iPhone 6s and 6s Plus I am getting a letter box effect on the sides (while the phone is being held horizontally) of my view. (My project is horizontal orrientation only)

This should be a simple fix of the constraints of the view. However this project was started over 2 years ago and I believe I may have used an Apple sample app to get started.

Therefore I'm at a loss to where such settings would be altered. I can easily change the SpriteKit overlay to match the screen with the appropriate key but as SceneKit is reliant on the view and the view is hidden due to my lack of knowledge in this area I cannot.

Comment: Did you try adding Launchscreen.storyboard to the project?

Comment: @NicolasMiari probably has it: if you don't have properly sized launch images for a device, or a launch screen storyboard that can auto-size to any device, iOS treats your app as though it's designed for whatever older screen size you do have launch images for. (Nothing actually SceneKit-related here, just general iOS app setup.)

Comment: Thankyou, fixed instantly. @NicolasMiari please add this as an answer so i can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL; DR:

To avoid letterboxing, you need to supply an Interface Builder launch screen (either .xib or .storyboard).

#### Background

When the iPhone 5 (the first to have a screen larger than 320x480 logical points) came out, Apple deviced a method for the system to tell if the app had been built with that screen size in mind, or if it was "legacy".

In addition to launch image of 320x480 (typically named Default.png, Default@2x.png for retina), you had to supply an additional one of 320x568 points (640x1136 pixels) for 4 inch displays.

If the system couldn't find that, the it would assume a "legacy" app and run it with black padding above and below the view, that is its "intended" size of 320x480 (so that the layout didn't break).

After that, the iPhone 6 and 6+ came out and using fixed bitmap images for launch screens became more and more meaningless; Apple wisely introduced xib and storyboard-based launch screens to support multiple screen sizes (e.g. with autolayout).

I haven't seen it first hand (because I adopted launch storyboards *before* getting my hands on a 6/6+), but I assume the same kind of letter-boxing happened for apps desiged with -at most- the iPhone 5/5s in mind (i.e., bundling a 4-inch ready launch image but no dynamic launch screen), and this is what happened to you this time.